# Angular Material 2 Form does not display

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material, angular2-forms, angular-material2

I am trying to add Forms and Inputs as described in Material 2 website. The Form does not display, but when I click on the form input it displays.

Additional Info (Update):

I am using a custom Theme.

```
$customTheme: mat-dark-theme($primary, $accent, $warn);
```

But when I change it to a lighter theme the form elements shows up.

```
$customTheme: mat-light-theme($primary, $accent, $warn);
```

I guess it has to do with the background and currentColor.

Comment: You should add more info so that somebody can help you.

Answer (score 2):

I could figure it out.

When using dark themes, the form's background expected is a dark color and not a white color.

I added a secondaryTheme with light background theme and used this in the form and it solved the issue.

```
$mainTheme: mat-dark-theme($primary, $accent, $warn);

$secondaryTheme : mat-light-theme($primary, $accent, $warn);

@include angular-material-theme($mainTheme);

.secondaryTheme {
    @include angular-material-theme($secondaryTheme);
}

<div class="secondaryTheme">

  <mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Input">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
  <textarea matInput placeholder="Textarea"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```